# 2 Way ANOVA array must not contain infs or NaNs Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, static, modeling, anova

I am currently trying to run a 2 way ANOVA on Python. My dataset is small as I have broken it into group averages already.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBTS7.png)

I have run the following code on it and am left without ideas on how to resolve the following error.

```
ANOVA = pd.read_excel("dataset.xlsx")

d_melt = pd.melt(ANOVA, id_vars=['Row Labels'], value_vars=['Average of FD 46-49', 'Average of FD 50-52', 'Average of FD 53-56'])

d_melt.columns = ['Row Labels', 'variable', 'value']

model = ols('value ~ C(Row Labels) + C(variable) + C(Row Labels):C(variable)', data=d_melt).fit()
anova_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
anova_table

ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

My dataset is small so I can see that there are no infs or NaNs so I am not sure why I am getting this error or how to resolve it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.